# My jquery with ajax do not work. Internal Server Error(500)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, lambda

This is my jquery:

```
$('#nmUsuario').on("dblclick", '.clique', function () {
    CarregaDados($(this).parent().find(".idusuario").text());    
})

function CarregaDados(ajaxParameter) {
    var str = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/CadastroAcesso/CarregaDadosPagina',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { _nivel: JSON.stringify(ajaxParameter) },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(1);
            $('#txtNome').val(data.result_carrega_pagina.NM_Usuario);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(2);
        }
    })
}
```

And this is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CarregaDadosPagina(int _nivel)
{
      RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

      var result_carrega_pagina = db.Usuario
            .Where(n => n.IDUsuario == _nivel)
            .Select(s => new { s.NM_Usuario, s.Usuario1, s.Email }).ToList();

      return Json(result_carrega_pagina, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But, my web page do not work. What I must to do? This is the error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of `500 (Internal Server Error)`

How I solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like your web service expects an integer, but you are passing it JSON.stringify(ajaxparameter).  Have you tried passing it just the integer value?

Comment: Try see with firebug the console, if it's 500 internal server error) sometimes it comes with extra information as others commented here, about integer instead of the string your are posting.

Comment: ajaxparameter is a int value. A variable has a integer value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You controller takes in an `int`, yet you pass in a `JSON.stringify(ajaxParameter)`. It needs to be in this format:

```
data: { _nivel: 1 }
```

Check your network traffic and put a breakpoint to make sure it is in the right format.

Comment: Ok, the problem with Internal Error solved, but I have this problem: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NM_Usuario' of undefined

Comment: @pnet sounds like another problem for another question.

Comment: Your returning a collection. `List` does not have a property `result_carrega_pagina` so `data.result_carrega_pagina.NM_Usuario` is undefined